# Checking if a node.js app has started properly using bash

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I wrote a node.js application and have written a bash script to start it and verify if it's running. I have my script run `npm start &` first, then I have a check to see if the ports I want open are open using netstat. The check works fine when I run it after the script is run, but during the running of the script, the check fails because the server has not fully started before the check is run. My code is below:

```
echo "Starting the server..."
npm start & > /dev/null 2>&1
if [[ -z $(sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :$portNum | grep node) ]] ; then
    echo -e "\tPort $portNum is not in use, something went wrong. Exiting."
else
    echo -e "\tPort $portNum is in use!"
fi
```

Is there a good way to take the above script and change it so that the check doesn't occur until the server is fully started? I don't want to use `sleep` if I can help it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `wait` call:

```
echo "Starting the server..." 
npm start & > /dev/null 2>&1 
wait
if [[ -z $(sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :$portNum | grep node) ]] ; then 
    echo -e "\tPort $portNum is not in use, something went wrong. Exiting." 
else 
    echo -e "\tPort $portNum is in use!" 
fi
```

The only limitation to this is that if npm daemonizes itself then it's no longer a child of the script so the `wait` command will have no effect (the reason for this is that a process daemonizes itself by terminating and spawning a new process that inherits its role).

Comment: I tried this, and I have the issue that it hangs at `[PM2] Starting app.js in fork_mode (1 instance)` in the background. It exists as a process and the app works fine, but for some reason it stays there and doesn't complete the wait, and instead hangs there forever. Do you know why this might be? I expect it to print out `[PM2] Done.` but it never does, however the app still starts and functions as intended.

Comment: @AndreasKralj are you using pm2? If so, try adding `process.send('ready');` in `startServer`. See the last comment in https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/661 for reference. I don't necessarily expect this to help, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Thanks, I'll test it out and see if it works! I appreciate it!

Comment: Unfortunately, that still didn't fix it, I appreciate the advice nonetheless. I'll keep working on it and I'll update the post if I find anything.

Comment: So I was actually able to fix the issue of the server startup hanging by removing the existing node_modules folder and doing an `npm install` again before running it. For some reason, when pulling the application down from GitHub, the node_modules folder that was contained in the application caused the startup to hang but still start. Since it now starts properly and does not hang, the `wait` command works perfectly. Thank you very much!